# Grouping the rows until meet certain conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, sequence

I have question on grouping rows together until meet certain conditions. Here is my dataframe.

```
| Gene     | directon       |intergenic_distance|
| -------- | -------------- |-------------------|
| fixA     | 11             |NA                 |
| fixB     | 11             |15                 |
| fixC     | 11             |51                 |
| fixX     | 11             |-3                 |
| kefF     | 11             |108                |
| kefC     | 11             |-7                 |
| apaH     | 12             |NA                 |
| apaG     | 12             |7                  |
```

I would like to group rows after intergenic_distance>50 and within same directon like below.

```
| Gene     | directon       |intergenic_distance|operon|
| -------- | -------------- |-------------------|------|
| fixA     | 11             |NA                 |1     |
| fixB     | 11             |15                 |1     |
| fixC     | 11             |51                 |2     |
| fixX     | 11             |-3                 |2     |
| kefF     | 11             |108                |3     |
| kefC     | 11             |-7                 |3     |
| apaH     | 12             |NA                 |4     |
| apaG     | 12             |7                  |4     |
```

I am thinking on using with, rle, rep, seq_along but I can't figure out how to do so. Thank you in advance!

```
dput(head(e_coli_operon,10))
structure(list(name = c("thrA", "thrB", "thrC", "yaaW", "yaaI", 
"mokC", "hokC", "insB", "insA", "yaaY"), start = c(337, 2801, 
3734, 10643, 11382, 16751, 16751, 19811, 20233, 21181), end = c(2799, 
3733, 5020, 11356, 11786, 16960, 16903, 20314, 20508, 21399), 
    strand = c(1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1), length = c(820L, 
    310L, 428L, 237L, 134L, 69L, 50L, 167L, 91L, 72L), pid = c(16127996L, 
    16127997L, 16127998L, 16128005L, 16128007L, 16128012L, 49175991L, 
    16128015L, 16128016L, 16128018L), gene = c("thrA", "thrB", 
    "thrC", "yaaW", "yaaI", "mokC", "hokC", "insB", "insA", "yaaY"
    ), synonym = c("b0002", "b0003", "b0004", "b0011", "b0013", 
    "b0018", "b4412", "b0021", "b0022", "b0024"), code = c("-", 
    "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), cog = c("COG0527E", 
    "COG0083E", "COG0498E", "COG4735S", "-", "-", "-", "COG1662L", 
    "COG3677L", "-"), product = c("fused aspartokinase I and homoserine dehydrogenase I", 
    "homoserine kinase", "threonine synthase", "conserved protein, UPF0174 family", 
    "conserved protein, UPF0412 family", "regulatory protein for HokC, overlaps CDS of hokC", 
    "toxic membrane protein, small", "IS1 transposase B", "IS1 repressor TnpA", 
    "predicted protein"), col = c("blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"), fill = c("blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
    "blue"), lty = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), lwd = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), pch = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 8, 8), cex = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), gene_type = c("arrows", 
    "arrows", "arrows", "arrows", "arrows", "arrows", "arrows", 
    "arrows", "arrows", "arrows"), directon = c("1", "1", "1", 
    "4", "4", "6", "6", "8", "8", "9"), intergenic_distance = c(82, 
    2, 1, 149, 26, NA, -209, NA, -81, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), groups = structure(list(directon = c("1", "4", "6", "8", 
"9"), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:5, 6:7, 8:9, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increment the `operon` value by 1 when :

- `intergenic_distance` is greater than 50 AND it is not `NA` OR
- current `directon` value is not same as the previous `directon` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(operon = cumsum(intergenic_distance > 50 & !is.na(intergenic_distance)|
                       directon != lag(directon, default = first(directon))) + 1)

#  Gene directon intergenic_distance operon
#1 fixA       11                  NA      1
#2 fixB       11                  15      1
#3 fixC       11                  51      2
#4 fixX       11                  -3      2
#5 kefF       11                 108      3
#6 kefC       11                  -7      3
#7 apaH       12                  NA      4
#8 apaG       12                   7      4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = c("fixA", "fixB", "fixC", "fixX", "kefF", 
"kefC", "apaH", "apaG"), directon = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L), intergenic_distance = c(NA, 15L, 51L, -3L, 108L, 
-7L, NA, 7L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me this error:Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: What is your dataframe called? You need to replace `df` with that.

Comment: I have replaced df with my data frame name but it gives me this error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `operon`.
x unable to find an inherited method for function ‘first’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
ℹ Input `operon` is `+...`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: directon = 1.

Comment: It does not give me any such error on the data that I am using. Can you test this on the data I have under my answer? Does it work for you on that data? Can you update your post with `dput(head(df, 10))` so that I can have a look on why you are getting that error on your data.

Comment: I've tried using data frame you created but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: That is strange since I don't get any such error on the same data. 1. Try restarting R and run it again on the data from my answer. 2. Try to remove any additional whitespaces from the code. Run this : `df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(operon = cumsum(intergenic_distance > 50 & !is.na(intergenic_distance)| directon != lag(directon, default = first(directon))) + 1)`

Comment: I have uploaded output of dput(head(df,10)) :) please take a look

Comment: It does not give me the error on your data as well but I noticed that your data is grouped so first you need to `ungroup` it and maybe you don't need `+ 1` in there.

Comment: I have ungrouped it but still showing the same error :( Is there any other method? By the way, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can you try `e_coli_operon <- transform(e_coli_operon, operon = cumsum(intergenic_distance > 50 & !is.na(intergenic_distance) | directon != dplyr::lag(directon, default = first(directon))))`

Comment: I removed the ```default=first(directon)))+1) ``` and it works! df %>% mutate(operon=cumsum(intergenic_distance>50 & !is.na(intergenic_distance)| directon!=lag(directon)))

Comment: I know what's the problem. The code you suggested requires ```gdata``` packages. Thanks for helping!